# Page moves on clicking a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written the following hyperlink

```
 <u><a class="delete_product" href="somelink" >delete</a></u>
```

and the following JS with it

```
 $( ".delete_product" ).on( "click", function() {

             var confirm_click=confirm("Delete this product");
             if(confirm_click===false)
             return false;
        });
```

when i click on this link, the entire product-row(for which this delete button is provided) moves left for 1/2 a second and then comes back to same position. Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: It has probably to do with something else. This code doesn't move your link.

Comment: Where does somelink refer to?

Comment: it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/8awRJ/

Comment: ok please put event.preventDefault in the scenario look at the fiddle

Comment: Check in your css if there is an a:active{...} directive. E.g. a:active{padding:0 0 0 5px;} will move it to the right 5px for 1/2 sec.

Comment: this link is deleting my product and it points to 'checkout.delete?cart_id=23'. something like this

Comment: @sudhar ya normal link will work fine. But its not working for me. Now it will be veryy difficult to paste the complete code for deleting a product in my project

Comment: let me check @tilokos

Comment: look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8awRJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-size was being overriden by the default font-size for link specified in the application. So on clicking the hyperlink, it grew to that font-size. Writing font-size :9px !important solved the issue

Comment: faced the same problem. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

use  `preventDefault`:

```
$( ".delete_product" ).on( "click", function(e) {
         var confirm_click=confirm("Delete this product");
         if(confirm_click===false)
         return false;
         e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: He asks page moves on clicking a hyperlink . Can event.preventDefault solves the problem - Milind Anantwar

Comment: Because i give the same solution in question comment that why i am asking

Comment: @sudhar: If that is happening due to refresh then yes.

Comment: preventdefault stops the complete action of the link.means the product doesnt delete.

Comment: event.preventDefault wherever in your code it reacts the same process

Comment: @Diffy:would be great if you can create the fiddle.

Comment: @milind, i am working with smarty templates in which i am deleting a product. so everything is written in terms of smarty php variables